# Async issues with geolocation and react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, react-google-maps

I'm implementing google maps directions in a react component and am struggling using navigator.geolocation as the starting location. Warning: I'm rather new to React and Node.

I have two main methods which are invoked within ComponentDidMount, **setStartLoc()** which sets the starting location to the navigator.geolocation result (if the user permits, otherwise it defaults to just a hardcoded location), and **GetDirections()** which queries the maps api for directions from the start-location to the destination-location (function arguments).

```py
componentDidMount() {
    //get geoLocation and print
    const startLoc = this.setStartLoc();
    console.log(startLoc);

    //set destination
    const destinationLoc =  "50.927884,  -1.299285";

    //get directions once start location returned
    startLoc.then(function(startLoc){
      this.getDirections(startLoc,destinationLoc).bind(this)
    })
  }
```

I've had issues with the asynchronous **getDirections** function, querying for directions before the user has a chance to permit their geolocation which results in an error returned from the api.

I've tried forcing **getDirections** to wait by implementing **setStartLoc** as a promise and using *.then*:

```
  setStartLoc = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log("in navigator");
            //get browser geolocation:
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
                resolve(pos.coords.latitude + ", " + pos.coords.longitude);
            });
        }
        else{
            //hardcoded alternative start location
            resolve("50.927044, -1.299964");
        }
    })
  }
```

As far as im aware this works in forcing **getDirections** to wait but it does result in the following typeError.

"TypeError: *this* is undefined"

Where *this* is referring to the following code in **componentDidMount**.

```
  this.getDirections(startLoc,destinationLoc).bind(this)
```

I've naturally tried adding/removing the bind but the same error occurs.

Could anyone please help with this error either by correcting the shown code or by suggesting an alternative method to making the **getDirection()** function wait to query once the **setStartLoc()** has returned?

The getDirections method and the rest of the component code was taken from this [guide](https://medium.com/@tarangsachdev/google-maps-directionsrenderer-with-reactjs-8074a4d0173e/) where full code for the component can be seen [here](https://github.com/tarangSachdev92/react-google-maps-demo/blob/master/src/components/Directions/DirectionRenderComponent.js) - to which I've added *setStartLoc* and changed *componentDidMount* as shown.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Max

Comment: use arrow notation ... e.g. `startLoc.then(function(startLoc){` -> `startLoc.then((startLoc) => {` - or move `.bind` to where it is **needed**, i.e. `function(startLoc){ .... }.bind(this)` if arrow notation is too scary

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track by promisifying the `setStartLoc` function, but, to get around your scoping issue, @Jaromanda X is absolutely right, you'll need an arrow function here.

With arrow functions, you could do something like this in your `componentDidMount`:

```
startLoc.then(startLoc => {
   this.getDirections(startLoc, destinationLoc);
});
```

Where `startLoc` is defined something like this:

```
setStartLoc = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log("in navigator");
        //get browser geolocation:
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          pos => {
            return resolve(pos.coords.latitude + ", " + pos.coords.longitude);
          },
          err => resolve("50.927044, -1.299964") // if user refuses access, return with default
        );
      }
      return resolve("50.927044, -1.299964");
    });
  };
```

For completeness, here is a [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-gates-o0jtq)